# Define List<T> in razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, generic-collections

Why when I try define List object there are inserts tag names instead 'T'?

[image]

Comment: Razor thinks `<string>` is the beginning of an HTML tag because of the `<` character. To get around this use parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose all code after @ in parentheses:

```
<td>@(Html.DropDownList("yyy", new SelectList(new List<string>{"",""})))</td>
```